# How to make Input box expand on click

Tags: user-input

I am working on my personal website. I need the input box expand when user clicks on it to input. (ex: twitter input box, it will expand when user click on it to write )

thank you

Answer (score 3):

Using CSS this is fairly simple: With the :focus pseudo class (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) you can easily detect input elements that are focussed. If you want fancy animations, use jquery to morph inbetween.

Comment: Animations are also possible using CSS3; I've found [an example, which matches the question](http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/transition/) - just replace `#width:hover` with `input:focus` in the example code.